# Xamarin MediaMager notifications on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I use the following code to start playing a local audio file. To my disappointment, no notification is shown on my Android emulator. After some digging, I notice that the Android [MediaNotificationManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/develop/MediaManager.Android/MediaNotificationManagerImplementation.cs) has all the code commented out.

I can see from a few other on GitHub, that other people does seem to have notifications (ironically, a few people seem to have problems getting rid of them - [Example](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/224)), so what do I need in order to get it?

```
IMediaFile mediaFile = new MediaFile(playRequest.Path, MediaFileType.Audio, ResourceAvailability.Local);
mediaFile = await CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaExtractor.ExtractMediaInfo(mediaFile);
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(mediaFile);

CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaNotificationManager.StartNotification(mediaFile);
CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaNotificationManager.UpdateNotifications(mediaFile, MediaPlayerStatus.Playing);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason. Notifications on Android require an Icon. By inspecting the source code of MediaNotificationManager, I found that on Android it actually handles notifications in a completely other class: [MediaNotificationManagerImplementation](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/master/MediaManager.Android/MediaSession/MediaNotificationManagerImplementation.cs) found in MediaSession.
There, I also learned that it will look for an icon of type `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` in the property `Art` on the metadata. Curiously, the property `ArtUri` is not used for anything.

If this property is null, it will look for a drawable in resources, with the name `xam_mediamanager_notify_ic`. If none is found, it will use the application icon.

Now, this solves all my needs for Android. However, it's handled quite differently on other platforms, and I've yet to find out how to set the art on UWP (and I've not tested iOS yet).